# MySQL syntax errors of equi join

Tags: mysql

i want to solve these two problems with equi join

1. For each customer order, list the order id, order date, order_source_id, source description, and the first and last name of the customer.
2. For each line in shipment_line, display the shipment_id, inv_id, ship_quantity, date_expected and date_received.

This is my syntax but it is showing error.

1.

```
SELECT order_id,order_date,order_source_id,source_desc,first,last    
FROM   customer,cust_order,order_source    
WHERE  (cust_order.order_source_id = order_source.order_source_id)    
AND    cust_order.cust_id = customer.cust_id;
```

2.

```
SELECT shipment_line.shipment_id,shipment_line.inv_id,shipment_line.date_recieved,shipment.date_expected
FROM   shipment_line, shipment
WHERE  shipment_line.shipment_id = shipment.shipment_id;
```

Comment: Could you please provide exact error message and table structure?

Answer (score 0):

You could have  ambiguous columns so you should add  the related  table name for each column:

```
SELECT cust_order.order_id
    , cust_order.order_date
    , cust_order.order_source_id
    , order_source.source_desc
    , customer.first
    , customer.last    
FROM   customer 
INNER JOIN cust_order ON cust_order.cust_id = customer.cust_id
INNER JOIN order_source  ON cust_order.order_source_id = order_source.order_source_id
```

And you should not use old (pre 1992) implicit join syntax based on where clause  but use explicit join class.

(Same problem for the second query).